# C Language program keeps getting bool and true and false as errors

Tags: c

I don't know what is wrong with the code but for some reason the C compiler keeps getting the bools of true and false and the bool itself in several errors. I have tried to fix the problems but my solutions didn't work. It's really baffling. All solutions and comments will be taken into account. Any help is appreciated.

```
/*
  *Standard C libraries
 */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 
 /*
  * Custom Headers
  */
  
  /*
   *Declaration of custom functions
   */
    bool get_string();
    bool get_double();
   
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    char mealChoice[100];
    double total = 0.0;
    double subTotal = 0.0;
    double mealCost = 0.0;
    const double HST = 0.15;
    const double ECO_DEPOSIT = 0.10;
    
    const char *menu =
    "There is one size of hot/cold beverage: 435ml\n"
    "Choices for hot beverages are: tea, cappachino, coffee\n"
    "Choices for cold beverages are: orange juice, milk, chocolate milk, bottled water\n"
    "Food choices for Breakfast: eggs, ham, bacon, toast with jam, and hasbrowns\n"
    "Food choices for Lunch: Pizza, lasagna, mac n cheese with bacon\n"
    "Food Choices for Dinner: Fish n' chips, sub with onion rings, fries, poutine, shephards pie, chicken alfredo\n"
    "Prices for Breakfast: $12.50, Lunch: $15.00 and Dinner $35.00\n";
    
    printf("%s\n", menu); // No need to call printf mutiple times.
    
    printf("Enter the customer's choice of Meal: ");
    get_string(mealChoice, sizeof mealChoice); // scanf(" %99[^\n]", mealChoice);
    
    printf("Enter the cost of meal: \n");
    get_double(&mealCost); // scanf(" %lf", &mealCost);
    
    subTotal = mealCost + (mealCost * HST);
    total = subTotal + ECO_DEPOSIT;
    
    printf("\nYour order: %s\n", mealChoice);
    printf("\nTotal cost: $%.2f\n", total);
    printf("\nThank you for your support!\nCome again!\n");
       
    return 0;
  }
  
  /*
    * Custom Functions  
    */
        bool get_string(char *in, const size_t size)
        {
            if (!fgets(in, size, stdin))
            {
                return false; // fgets failed.
            }           
            else
            {
                size_t last = strcspn(in, "\n");
                in[last] = '\0';
                return true;        
            }           
        }
        
        bool get_double(double *d)
        {
            char in[100];
            if (!get_string(in, sizeof in))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return sscanf(in, "%lf", d) == 1;
            }
            
            
        }
```

Comment: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: @Kevin Thanks much appreciated.  I should've known that.

Comment: @Kevin The program runs smoothly now.  Much appreciated for the help.